# Use array data with ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, ajax, symfony

here is my issue.

I proceed to an ajax request which send me a value for an object (here a mission).
Then i want to print that value using ng-bind-html with angular js.

But here is the thing, the ng-bind is going to take the last value from the ajax request.

So starting with what i have right now, i wanted to use ma be an array or something else to get differents id for m data

```
$.each(missions, function(key,mission){

                $scope.posDate="Calcul en cours";
                $http({
                    method : "POST",
                    url : "getDatesBasket",
                    data:   {"mission":mission},
                    async:false
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.posDate=response['data'];
                },function errorCallback(response) {
                    $scope.posDate="ERREUR DATE";
                });



var infoContent = <div ng-controller="missionCtrl"> <p ng-bind-html="posDate"></p></div>
```

I hope you can see the issue, each time posDate is erased by the next ending ajax request.

If you have an idea that would be great, i've spent more than 2 days with that crap.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know that option `async`, that you are using, doesn't works. There is no simple way to do syncronous http requests in angular.

For your problem, if I fully understand what you want to do, you can get `response.config` that holds the data you've send on request and search in your missions array for that specific mission in every response that you get.

Something like this:

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {

    $.each(missions, function(key, mission) {
        if(mission == response.config.data.mission)
           mission.postData = response.data; //Or wherever you want to put the data
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes async:false isn't working and that was the begenning of my problems :(

But after that i tried that method with ng bind.

My response contains only a string llike "Today" for example. So i can't see why am i going to do  response.config.data.mission.

I was more thinking about something like

$scope.posDate[k]=response['data'];

var infoContent = <div ng-controller="missionCtrl"> <p ng-bind-html="posDate[k]"></p></div>

But i have no idea how to do it

Comment: My proposed solution does this in a slightly different way, searching for the mission who corresponds to the response that came. So your html would be :
_<p ng-bind-html="missions[k].posData">_

Comment: So, that means that in my controler, when i send the data, i can't just send "today" like now; but i'm going to send something like "mission_id":"today" inside my json ? I'll try this monday as soon as i can.